# How do I copy values from other files and append them to each other and put them into another field? I'm using Yii2 and a newbie

Tags: sql, database, yii2

For example:

```
account_type: 1
account_type2: 100
account_type3: 200
account_type4: 001
```

And would like to put them into a account_code field in this format:

account_code: 1-100-200-001

What query should I do to achieve this? Sorry, I'm a newbie. I'm using Yii2. Thanks!

Comment: should work with CONCAT like: CONCAT(account_type, "-", account_type2, "-", account_type3, "-", account_type4)

Comment: Could you wrap that up as an UPDATE statement and post that as an answer Esteban?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: Can I use that concat in the actionCreate()? It stores values on the field then concat it to the account_code? Is it doable? I dont know where to put the concat. Still learning Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if all the columns are in the same table

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

$command = $connection->createCommand("UPDATE table_name SET account_code = CONCAT(account_type, "-", account_type2, "-", account_type3, "-", account_type4) WHERE SOME_condition");

$result = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: your model preferably.

Answer (score 0):

A one line method to achieve this is:

```
$result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("UPDATE table_name SET account_code = CONCAT(account_type, "-", account_type2, "-", account_type3, "-", account_type4) WHERE SOME_condition")->queryAll();
```

Comment: Where do I put the code? On the controller, actionCreate?

Comment: Since this is an update query, I think this should be inside the actionUpdate.